# Sum up average pixel values of all images: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have to set a threshold based on a pixel value to remove some images in a folder and I need to know the standard deviation of pixel values. Therefore, I need to sum up all mean-pixel-values.

The followings are what I have tried

The following codes demonstrate how the output of np.mean() look like

```
import os,glob
from PIL import Image
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from statistics import stdev 

path = "/Users/Xin/Desktop/SVM-Image-Classification-master/test"
# Delete images with the low pixel value
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    images = Image.open(os.path.join(path,filename))  
    print(np.mean(images))
    #if np.mean(images) < 20:
        #os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
#print(len(os.listdir(path)))
```

Output as follow, the value is between 0 ~ 255. The smaller the values are, more black the images are.

```
12.685516357421875
14.462142944335938
12.24658203125
9.507644653320312
18.701019287109375
10.004150390625
18.128433227539062
12.625930786132812
```

The following codes are what I tried

```
path = "/Users/Xin/Desktop/SVM-Image-Classification-master/test"
# Delete images with the low pixel value
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    images = Image.open(os.path.join(path,filename))  
    L = list[round(np.mean(images),2)]
    totalvalue = sum(L)
    print(totalvalue)
    #if np.mean(images) < 20:
        #os.remove(os.path.join(path, filename))
#print(len(os.listdir(path)))
```

The error indicates as follow

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64
```

Can anyone give me a help?
Many thanks!

Comment: it's list() not list[]

Comment: `list[round(np.mean(images),2)]` tells python give me the `round(np.mean(images),2)`th element of the list `list`. Which doesn't make sense, because it's a float

Answer (score 0):

This function can be substituted for standard deviation.

```
def function(image):
    (R, G, B)= function_for_rgb(image)
    std_dev = statistics.stdev([R, G, B]) #standard deviation
    return  round(std_dev,2)
```